# Unsatisfied Linker Error : library file not found

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am writing test cases for a class that calls the constructor of another class that has a static block that loads a c++ library,

```
static
  {
          System.loadLibrary("PixelProxy_jni");
  }
```

I have specified the library path as,

```
-Djava.libarary.path=C:\Users\Desktop\libPixelProxy_jni.so
```

in the vm arguments in eclipse, but still it doesn't work.

Please help me find a solution for this

stack trace

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no PixelProxy_jni in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at com.XrayPixelProxyInputStream.<clinit>(XrayPixelProxyInputStream.java:36)
    at com.RadImageReader.readImage(RadImageReader.java:57)
    at servicedisplay.ServiceImageDisplayer.showImage(ServiceImageDisplayer.java:124)
    at servicedisplay.test1.ServiceImageDisplayerTest.testShowImageStringIntIntIntIntIntInt(ServiceImageDisplayerTest.java:95)
```

Comment: I think eclipse overwrites the java library path when running the app, did you try printing it to be sure it points to the correct location?

Comment: Yes I just printed it and its not referring to the path I specified. How do I set it then?

Answer (score 1):

From that file path, it looks like you're on windows, which means that `loadLibrary` will not look for a file named `libPixelProxy_jni.so`, it will look for a file named `PixelProxy_jni.dll`. (You can find out exactly what it will look for by using [`System.mapLibraryName`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#mapLibraryName-java.lang.String-).)

You can either find a `.dll` of the library, compile one yourself, or try `System.load`, which allows you to load a native library from an absolute path:

```
System.load("C:\Users\Desktop\libPixelProxy_jni.so");
```

But that will only work if the library was actually compiled for windows.

Comment: Yes I am on Windows7. I did `System.load("C:\Users\Desktop\libPixelProxy_jni.so");` as you said, but It threw me a new exception. `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Desktop\libPixelProxy_jni.so: Can't load this .dll (machine code=0x101) on a IA 32-bit platform`

Comment: @hushie Looks like it's a 64-bit dll, you'd have to use a 64-bit version of Java as well. Or the other way around, get a 32-bit version of the library.

Comment: In my test class I am accessing the method that calls the constructor of another class which contains the static block. So when I run that test method I get the above exception. Is there any other workaround other that changing the java version?

Comment: @hushie The class that you're testing has an indirect dependency on that library, even if there was a way to not load the library (I don't know any), the class probably wouldn't work properly. Since you tagged with mockito, I'll suggest using dependency injection of the class that loads the library (if you can change the class being tested) and then mock that dependency.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change the class being tested.

Comment: @hushie You could try asking another question about this new problem. Maybe someone else has another idea. I can't give a final answer, but it seems impossible then.

Comment: Hmmm okay will do